# Hide button when opening a previously hidden section

Tags: jquery

I have a page of text, the first paragraph is visible and the rest of the paragraphs are hidden and can be made visible by clicking the 'read more' link... but the 'read more' button is still visible when the rest of the paragraphs are opened.  I'd like the 'read more' link to hide when it's been clicked on and shown again if/when the user closes the container holding the previously hidden paragraphs  Below is what I have working at this moment, this might be really easy but I’m a jQuery noob.

Thanks

```
$(function()
{
    $(".about_text_wrap .readMore_aboutText")
        .next()
        .hide()
        .append('<input type="button" value="close" />');

    $(".about_text_wrap .readMore_aboutText").click(function()
    {

        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().find('.more_about_textWrap').slideUp("fast");
        $this.next().slideDown("slow");

    });

    $("input").click(function()
    {

        $(this).parent().slideUp();

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="about_text_wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p><span class="readMore_aboutText">Read More</span>
    <div class="more_about_textWrap">
        <p>Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. </p>
        <p>Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. </p>
        <p>Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. </p>
    </div><!-- about_text_moreWrap -->
</div><!-- about_text_wrap-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.hide()` to hide the `read more` link when it is clicked and `.show()` to show it back when your close button is clicked like this:

```
$(function () {

    $(".about_text_wrap .readMore_aboutText").next().hide().append('<input type="button" value="close" />');

    $(".about_text_wrap .readMore_aboutText").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.hide();
        $this.parent().find('.more_about_textWrap').slideUp("fast");
        $this.next().slideDown("slow");
    });

    $("input").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().slideUp(function() {
            $(".about_text_wrap .readMore_aboutText").show();
        });
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LYFMD/)**

Comment: Thanks Felix this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After hiding you are appending which will not work. Use [end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) and then append which make sure to append your div in correct structure:

```
$(".about_text_wrap .readMore_aboutText").next().hide().end().append('<input type="button" value="close" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility could be to simplify your jQuery stuff but then you need to tweak your HTML and I don't know if this is an option:

jQuery/JS:

```
$(".readMore_aboutText").click(function() {
    $(".more_about_textWrap").slideToggle();
    $(".readMore_aboutText").toggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
.more_about_textWrap { display: none; }
.hideMe { display: none; }
```

HTML:

```
<span class="readMore_aboutText">Read More</span>
<span class="readMore_aboutText hideMe">Close</span>
```

See this [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nzgpG/).